# Explain the difference between drawable, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-hdpi

Tags: android, android-screen-support, android-drawable

I have a rough idea of what each of these directories are for, but I'm not really clear on the concept and I have some specific questions.

For example, what are the target DPIs for each directory? When you create an asset, should it be at that target DPI or should it be at the more normal 72dpi screen DPI? If you're targeting multiple devices, is it ever appropriate to put a PNG in drawable or should you always have multiple versions slightly tailored to the specific screens?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm hoping for something more than a link to the docs. I've read/skimmed the screen_support docs, but I still have the specific questions above.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As the others have suggested, the Android online documentation has great articles on this. However, I'm going to try and list here some quick and helpful tips:

1. Consider MDPI is `1`. Then, LDPI is `0.75` and HDPI is `1.5`. What that means is that if you have a drawable that is, say, `50x50` on a MDPI screen it will have to be `~37x37` on a LDPI screen and `75x75` on a HDPI screen, **in order to appear at roughly the same physical size** on each screen (i.e. 2cm if you put a ruler on the screen). Also, your computer screen is *most probably* MDPI, which is why it's recommended to start with MDPI drawables and then resize them: the **physical size** of the drawable will be very close between your computer screen and an MDPI Android device. If you view an HDPI drawable on your computer and on an HDPI device you will notice that it's **much** bigger (again, **physically** -- put a ruler on it style) on the PC screen.
2. If you do not supply special drawables for each density, Android will scale the closest one available automatically.
3. You should not consider the DPI of a device to have anything to do with screen size and/or number of pixels and/or resolution and/or aspect ratio. A device could be very small and have an HDPI screen or very large and have an LDPI screen. The whole point of this density-differentiation is to have things **look the same size** on all devices, **not** fit the same on all devices. For example, if a drawable fills the whole screen on one MDPI device do not expect it to do the same on another MDPI device. Also, do not expect to "see the same thing" on different DPI devices. Most HDPI devices actually have **more** space than lower DPI devices. For example, if a `ListView` can show 5 items on a MDPI device it might be able to show 6 items on an HDPI device, in spite of the fact that the `ListView` items have the same density-independent (i.e. 1.5 times larger on HDPI than on MDPI) height.

I might have gone a bit offtopic, but these are things I have learned in time by banging my head against them. Just trying to save someone else's headache :)

Comment: This might help a little as well: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/

Comment: thanks @Felix for clear explanation. I have read many other posts but could'nt understood ! this is really clear now for me !

Comment: To add onto your first point, XHDPI is `2` and XXHDPI is `3`. So with your example of a drawable that is `50x50` on an MDPI screen, it will have to be `100x100` on an XHDPI screen and `150x150` on an XXHDPI screen.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but Android has a great online doc with examples so for this type of question the answer is:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

There are no exact DPI values for each folder. Every folder is related to some range. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

These directories must hold drawable resources optimized for some screen density. You can hold just one drawable for HDPI or any other, but on devices with other DPI settings image will be resized somehow and it will take time/resources. Also low DPI image will look poor on devices with HDPI.

Answer (score 1):

Due to different screen size and resolutions, Android lets you arrange your drawable images according to folders. Images for high dpi displays should be placed in hdpi and similarly mdpi and ldpi. The default folder for the drawables is drawables if the operating system does not match any dpi category or the resources is not found in special dpi directories the system picks the resource from the drawables directory.

The size are not exact but upto 130dpi it is considered small, from 130 to 180 it can be considered mdpi, from 180 to 200 it can be considered as hdpi and the higher is classified as xdpi.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html