# Where to insert images in eclipse for android

Tags: android, image, android-screen-support, android-drawable

I am new to Android and I need to use images in my XML file.

A tutorial says that I have to place them in `drawable` directory, but I can't find it as I find `drawable-hdpi`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

drawable folder is divided into into three part according to device screen size  h- high, M- Medium, L- Low  because in android different size of device available in the market and android device screen divide into three type h,m,l based on density specific according to device size android pick the image from specific drawable folder h ,m ,l if you dont want to density specification in your application then add new folder  with the name of drawable.

I hope it is more use full to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the drawable folder yourself by `right-clicking "res" -> "New" -> "Folder"` and naming it `drawable`.If you do not need your images to be density-specific, you can put your images there.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own `drawable` folder in `res` directory. But remember keep the images in that folder which are common for all screen size devices. `drwable-hdpi` means this directory contained the images will be loaded when the device has higher dpi. similarly `drawable-mdpi` and `drawable-ldpi` are there.

Answer (score 0):

Those which you found are drawable folders.. Insert the images in all three of them. So that at time of change in definition of screen images can be changed accordingly. For now, Insert same image in all three of them.

You can create your own drawable folder. But its good to use these at first then when you run your application on device you will come to know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

**drawable-hdpi drawable-mdpi etc are the different  type of drawables** . you can keep your images in these folder (any one at the initial level).

But they have some diffrence according to the resolution of the screen & density of android device. Further you can check the diffrence between them and keep the images as per need.

see this for more details: [Explain the difference between drawable, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-hdpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373085/explain-the-difference-between-drawable-drawable-ldpi-drawable-mdpi-and-drawabl)

and [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a drawable folder in the /res folder of your project and put your images there.

drawable-hdpi(mdpi/ldpi) are used separate different resources for different type of screen. take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to know more about multiple screen handling

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this question is rather dated, but...it came up when I Googled the issue of inserting images into an Eclipse Android project, so....

Actually, those folders are [mipmaps](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/version1.1/glspec1.1/node84.html) and they are used by the graphics subsystem to provide seamless zooming, as well. I would suggest creating proper mipmaps using an editor, as opposed to providing only one resolution choice.