# Difference between hdpi and large-hdpi?

Tags: android, android-layout

Does anybody know the difference between hdpi and large-hdpi?
mdpi and large-mdpi?
large-mdpi and sw600dp?

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Thanks.

Comment: Similar question that might match your question :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373085/explain-the-difference-between-drawable-drawable-ldpi-drawable-mdpi-and-drawab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the API documentation:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
>
> ... two devices that both report a screen size of normal
>   might have actual screen sizes and aspect ratios that are slightly
>   different when measured by hand. Similarly, two devices that report a
>   screen density of hdpi might have real pixel densities that are
>   slightly different. Android makes these differences abstract to
>   applications, so you can provide UI designed for the generalized sizes
>   and densities and let the system handle any final adjustments as
>   necessary.

Also note (same link):

> Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), these size groups are
>   deprecated in favor of a new technique for managing screen sizes based
>   on the available screen width

This is where "smallestWidth sw600dp" and friends come in:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts

The main issue is "How can the Android API accomodate the wide range of devices with the minimum effort on the part of the developer?"

'Hope that helps

Comment: but why on that link there are no any data in table 3 for Large screen size for HDPI density?

Comment: Table 1/Figure 4 is the "old, 'size groups' way" - ldpi, mdpi, etc.  Table 2 is the "new Android 3.2++ way".  Table 3 refers to skins available in the SDK for the s/w emulator.