# Drawable concept issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

i am new to android and i just have one query regarding concept of drawable:- **"if i put all images of my project in all - Drawable-hdpi, Drawable-mdpi, Drawable-ldpi does the images fetched will be automatically done on the basis of screen size and density"**.
Or it does not make any sense making multiple copies of image in all drawable..??

Comment: Android will do that automatically, else why would it even provide such a concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources. The android documentation in the link gives details on providing alternate resources for drawable.

I also found a link where the answer accepted has a good explanation on the topic.[Explain the difference between drawable, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-hdpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373085/explain-the-difference-between-drawable-drawable-ldpi-drawable-mdpi-and-drawab).

Drawables are fetched by android based on screen size and density.
If you do not supply special drawables for each density, Android will scale the closest one available automatically. Scaling the drawables on some devices may look odd. So it is better to provide different drawables based on screen size and density.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is this:
Android can and will upscale / downscale an image according to screen size and pixel density, but it might not be perfect, and this process costs computational power.
If you're using a photo editing program to create smaller / larger photos *correctly* like you want it to look, you will get better results, and you will get them faster.

Answer (score 0):

yes thats how it works based on the screen size they will be fetched, there is different approaches for graphical assets depending on how you design your app, here is the calculations for the different folders:

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
Generalised Dpi values for screens:

ldpi Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi)
mdpi Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
hdpi Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
Therefore generalised size of your resources (assuming they are full screen):

ldpi
Vertical = 426 * 120 / 160 = 319.5px
Horizontal = 320 * 120 / 160 = 240px
mdpi
Vertical = 470 * 160 / 160 = 470px
Horizontal = 320 * 160 / 160 = 320px
hdpi
Vertical = 640 * 240 / 160 = 960px
Horizontal = 480 * 240 / 160 = 720px
xhdpi
Vertical = 960 * 320 / 160 = 1920px
Horizontal = 720 * 320 / 160 = 1440px

px = dp*dpi/160
```

also if you are drawing to screen using opengl or surfaceview or something like that you can just make one copy of images in assets folder and stretch to screen when you draw, and just store your icon in the drawable folders, theres different approaches depending on how you design your app is what im trying to say