# How Android choose between screen density

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, pixel, android-resources

For example, I provide some image in **ldpi**, **mdpi** and **xhdpi** folder.

When I run app on device with **hdpi** density, which resource will it pick - **ldpi** or **mdpi**?

Comment: Android will pick the one that user's phone is in that category or maybe the nearest, there are ways to find out which it will pick, but in many scenarios it wont concern you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case android chooses **mdpi*.
You can read more about [How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)

Comment: Do you assume this due to this (from the article)? "When selecting resources based on the screen size qualifiers, the system will use resources designed for a screen smaller than the current screen if there are no resources that better match"

Comment: Frankly speaking it' my experience, but you can read about it in the end of article. **When selecting resources based on the screen size qualifiers, the system will use resources designed for a screen smaller than the current screen if there are no resources that better match**

Answer (score 4):

Taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

> If no matching resource is available, the system uses the default
>   resource and scales it up or down as needed to match the current
>   screen size and density The "default" resources are those that are not
>   tagged with a configuration qualifier. For example, the resources in
>   drawable/ are the default drawable resources. The system assumes that
>   default resources are designed for the baseline screen size and
>   density, which is a normal screen size and a medium-density. As such,
>   the system scales default density resources up for high-density
>   screens and down for low-density screens, as appropriate. However,
>   when the system is looking for a density-specific resource and does
>   not find it in the density-specific directory, it won't always use the
>   default resources. The system may instead use one of the other
>   density-specific resources in order to provide better results when
>   scaling. For example, when looking for a low-density resource and it
>   is not available, **the system prefers to scale-down the high-density
>   version of the resource**, because the system can easily scale a
>   high-density resource down to low-density by a factor of 0.5, with
>   fewer artifacts, compared to scaling a medium-density resource by a
>   factor of 0.75.

Answer (score 1):

Consider MDPI is 1. Then, LDPI is 0.75 and HDPI is 1.5. What that means is that if you have a drawable that is, say, 50x50 on a MDPI screen it will have to be ~37x37 on a LDPI screen and 75x75 on a HDPI screen.

If you do not supply special drawables for each density, Android will scale the closest one available automatically.

**You should not consider the DPI of a device to have anything to do with screen size and/or number of pixels and/or resolution and/or aspect ratio. A device could be very small and have an HDPI screen or very large and have an LDPI screen**

> ldpi  Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).
>   mdpi  Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is
>   the baseline density.) hdpi   Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens
>   (~240dpi). xhdpi  Resources for extra-high-density (xhdpi) screens
>   (~320dpi). xxhdpi Resources for extra-extra-high-density (xxhdpi)
>   screens (~480dpi). xxxhdpi    Resources for
>   extra-extra-extra-high-density (xxxhdpi) uses (~640dpi). Use this for
>   the launcher icon only, see note above.

please check http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6373533/2826147

Comment: Thanks for your answer, information is useful. But the question was, which resource would be taken.